# finding a corresponding cell value of a max value

Tags: python-3.6, xlrd

I am new to Python. I have a spreadsheet with two columns: date, values.

I need to find the max value in the value column, then find the date of the max value.

to find the max value, I am using:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
max_value = max(sheet.col_values(1,1,None)
max_value_date = ???
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
col_val = sheet.col_values(1,1,None) # the second column  
maxval = max(col_val)
maxpos = col_val.index(maxval)+2 
maxtime = sheet.cell_value(maxpos,0)
```